# How to use different GoogleAnalytics tracking id for separate targets in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics

I have 2 targets of the same app (one free, one paid) and I wish to configure 2 different Google Analytics tracking codes & bundle ids. 
Goole Analytics SDK uses the file `GoogleService-Info.plist` but I could not find any way to configure another info.plist file for the SDK.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Just add the second `GoogleService-Info.plist` to your project (files should be in the different folders). Then the first file add to target `Free` and second to target `Paid`.

Comment: When I change one of them, the other is changed as well..

Comment: I did as you told but it crashes: "reason: 'Error configuring Google services: ... Check formatting and location of GoogleService-Info.plist"

Comment: Do you just make `Add Files to ..` with already exist file? It should be a new `GoogleService-Info.plist` file which placed in the different folder. Check the path to file in the `xcode` right tab `Identity and Type` and ensure that paths are different.

Answer (score 0):

you can add two files with same name in `different targets` but you can not add two files with same name in `same target`

For adding two `GoogleService-Info.plist` you need to create two different folders in which you will add these file but be care full to add these files in their respective targets

[image]

[image]